# Объединить вывод 2 столбцов в 1 столбец

Tags: mysql

Допустим надо объединить вывод и 'адрес' и 'второй_адрес' в одну колонку 
'все_адреса'.

SELECT `адреса1`.`адрес` as первый_адрес , `адреса1`.`второй_адрес` as второй_адрес

вот так:

`SELECT (`адреса1`.`адрес`,`адреса1`.`второй_адрес`) as все_адреса`

```
'первый_адрес'
маяковского
площадь победы

'второй_адрес'
дмитровское шоссе


'все_адреса'
маяковского
дмитровское шоссе
площадь победы
```

Как и можно ли это сделать?

Comment: через `union` пробовали?

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev
Да это то что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (адреса1.адрес) as все_адреса FROM адреса1
UNION
SELECT (адреса1.второй_адрес) as все_адреса FROM адреса1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(адреса1.адрес, ' ',  адреса1.второй_адрес) FROM ....
```

Даже скорее так:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ",адреса1.адрес, адреса1.второй_адрес) FROM ....
```

т.к. в первом варианте, если в одном из 2 столбцов будет NULL то вернется NULL, второй вариант пустые значения проигнорирует

Comment: Нет, concat врезает одно поле в другое 

`||маяковского дмитровское шоссе||
||площадь победы дмитровское шоссе||`

А нужно добавить в конец один столбец в другой

`||маяковского ||
||дмитровское шоссе||
||площадь победы||`