# Объединение колонок в одну в сложном запросе Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, объединение

У меня вопрос похожий на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429427/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-1-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86/1221166?noredirect=1#comment2136882_1221166).

Есть таблица Auftraege в которой есть колонка сумм Gewinn (Auftraege.Gewinn). К этой таблице через LEFT JOIN подключается 2 раза таблица Vertreterstamm с колонкой имен Suchname (Vertreterstamm.Suchname) через ключи Auftraege.Vertreter1 и Auftraege.Vertreter2. Именам (Vertreter1 и Vertreter2) присваиваются суммы Gewinn поровну если имена разные, если имя Vertreter1 и Vertreter2 одинаковое то сумма Gewinn дается только один раз этому имени.

Нужно пересобрать как-то таблицу, чтоб он выводил уникальные значения Vertreterstamm.Suchname с двух колонок Vertreter1 и Vertreter2, и суммировал для этих уникальных значений суммы Auftraege.Gewinn, когда эти уникальные значения были и Vertreter1, и Vertreter1.

```
Исходный результат:
Gewinn  Vertreter_1 Vertreter_2
50  Maria   Thomas
75  Maria   Maria
40  Ivan    Ivan
80  Ivan    Thomas
100 Thomas  Maria
```

```
Ожидаемый результат:
Gewinn  Vertreter
225 Maria ///(50 + 75 + 100)
120 Ivan ///(40 + 80)
230 Thomas ///(50 + 80 + 100)
```

Версия СУБД:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11-GDR) (KB4535706) - 13.0.5622.0 (X64)   Dec 15 2019 08:03:11   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Скрин: http://prntscr.com/w6emru

Ссылка на dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2543a0efcb882fd275bb5dfd79ab148

```sql
CREATE TABLE Auftraege
(
Gewinn INT,
Vertreter1 INT,
Vertreter2 INT,
);
CREATE TABLE Vertreterstamm
(
OID INT,
Suchname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) 
VALUES (50, 1, 3);
INSERT Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) 
VALUES (75, 1, 1);
INSERT Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) 
VALUES (40, 2, 2);
INSERT Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) 
VALUES (80, 2, 3);
INSERT Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) 
VALUES (100, 3, 1);
INSERT Vertreterstamm(OID, Suchname) 
VALUES (1, 'Maria');
INSERT Vertreterstamm(OID, Suchname) 
VALUES (2, 'Ivan');
INSERT Vertreterstamm(OID, Suchname) 
VALUES (3, 'Thomas');

SELECT
Gewinn,
Vertreterstamm_1.Suchname AS Vertreter_1,
Vertreterstamm_2.Suchname AS Vertreter_2
FROM
Auftraege
LEFT JOIN Vertreterstamm Vertreterstamm_1 ON (Vertreterstamm_1.OID=Auftraege.Vertreter1)
LEFT JOIN Vertreterstamm Vertreterstamm_2 ON (Vertreterstamm_2.OID=Auftraege.Vertreter2)
```

Comment: *Сам скрипт замудреный, будет круто даже если просто покажете как объединить колонки* Ну так упростите. Кому он нужен, замудрёный скрипт, если проблема - в одной узкой точке? Сделайте таблицу t1 с полями Gewinn, Vertreter1 и Vertreter2, и таблицу t2 с полем Suchname, выложите для такой модели CREATE TABLE и INSERT INTO (3-4 записи на таблицу), плюс требуемый результат на именно таких данных с пояснением по конкретным строкам и значениям, что и где происходит. Вам подскажут, что и как - а дальше Вы обратно этот алгоритм размотаете на этот страхолюдный скрипт.

Comment: @Akina https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=73ae2e36e1cd83739c5e8cd4b48ea65e012f2043f3a69d31eab5d607c5cd0089 Скрин: http://prntscr.com/w67ejs Нужно вывести уникального Vertreter с общим Gewinn когда он Vertreter_1 и Vertreter_2

Comment: Походу fiddle не очень-то public... попробуйте перенести на dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @Akina https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66c1aa30860abd0b3b8d093e66bdab0f

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой пост и добавьте желаемый результат на основе примера данных.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky готово, спасибо

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: #3 and #4 все еще отсутствуют.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky теперь правильно?

Comment: @Akina, нет, Ваш ответ неверный к сожалению. Я поправил вопрос, добавил желаемый результат

Comment: Обновил ответ. PS. Если Вы не будете до конца разбираться в ответах, даже когда они не дают требуемого результата - Вам будет трудно...

Comment: *Если я правильно понял про версию СУБД, то это MS SQL Management studio 18.2* Нет, неверно. SSMS - это клиентское приложение, а нужна версия сервера БД. Которую легко получить запросом `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: @Akina спасибо Вам за наставление но я новичок в SQL как уже указывал. За ответ большое спасибо, теперь все верно.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky поправил, спасибо

Comment: @Akina теперь придется еще недельку помучаться чтоб имплементировать Ваше решение в тот ужасный скрипт )

Comment: @Akina YitzhakKhabinsky видимо не помогут мне подобные решения - http://prntscr.com/w6g7rb. Мне нужно это сделать в DevExpress Dashboard Designer. Если б кто-то помог поправить исходник так чтоб получить требуемый результат... Исходник я сюда закинул, если кто-то все же сможет с ним помочь: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a991af14d791c8d14d0da9b78e76147a

Comment: вроде получилось пересобрать скрипт. Если что лежит тут https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa25231dbaadda9f5298cc09f6d30c39

Comment: @Akina большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее решение.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @Auftraege TABLE (Gewinn INT,Vertreter1 INT,Vertreter2 INT);
INSERT INTO @Auftraege(Gewinn, Vertreter1, Vertreter2) VALUES 
(50, 1, 3),
(75, 1, 1),
(40, 2, 2),
(80, 2, 3),
(100, 3, 1);

DECLARE @Vertreterstamm TABLE (OID INT,Suchname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Vertreterstamm(OID, Suchname) VALUES 
(1, 'Maria'),
(2, 'Ivan'),
(3, 'Thomas');

-- Просто чтобы видеть
SELECT Gewinn
    , Vertreter1
    , IIF(Vertreter1 <> Vertreter2, Gewinn, IIF(Vertreter1 = Vertreter2,Gewinn,0)) AS Gewinn1
    , Vertreter2
    , IIF(Vertreter1 <> Vertreter2, Gewinn, 0) AS Gewinn2 
FROM @Auftraege;

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT Gewinn
        , Vertreter1
        , IIF(Vertreter1 <> Vertreter2, Gewinn, IIF(Vertreter1 = Vertreter2,Gewinn,0)) AS Gewinn1
        , Vertreter2
        , IIF(Vertreter1 <> Vertreter2, Gewinn, 0) AS Gewinn2 
    FROM @Auftraege
), cte AS
(
    SELECT Vertreter1, SUM(Gewinn1) AS Gewinn FROM rs
    GROUP BY Vertreter1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Vertreter2, SUM(Gewinn2) AS Gewinn FROM rs
    GROUP BY Vertreter2
)
SELECT v.*, SUM(Gewinn) AS Gewinn
FROM cte INNER JOIN @Vertreterstamm AS v
    ON cte.Vertreter1 = v.OID
GROUP BY OID, Suchname
ORDER BY OID;
```

**Результат**

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| OID | Suchname | Gewinn |
+-----+----------+--------+
|   1 | Maria    |    225 |
|   2 | Ivan     |    120 |
|   3 | Thomas   |    230 |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понимаю задачу (которую я до сих пор не понимаю вообще), то требуется нечто близкое к

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT Gewinn, Vertreter1 Vertreter FROM Auftraege
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Gewinn, Vertreter2 FROM Auftraege)
SELECT SUM(Gewinn) / 2 Gewinn, Vertreterstamm.Suchname AS Vertreter
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN Vertreterstamm ON (Vertreterstamm.OID=cte.Vertreter)
GROUP BY Vertreterstamm.Suchname
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19f48436ac9951e1bd532b9d1f31c174)

Даже если нужно что-то иное - адаптировать несложно, идея останется той же.

---

Появление требуемого ответа прояснило задачу. Как я и говорил - идея не меняется, нужна минимальная доработка.

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT Gewinn, Vertreter1 Vertreter FROM Auftraege
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Gewinn, Vertreter2 FROM Auftraege WHERE Vertreter1 != Vertreter2)
SELECT SUM(Gewinn) Gewinn, Vertreterstamm.Suchname AS Vertreter
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN Vertreterstamm ON (Vertreterstamm.OID=cte.Vertreter)
GROUP BY Vertreterstamm.Suchname
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8cd79331bccd7d3a4a7c072355cf6fd)

Comment: Хорошее решение.